# Where is the nodeService bean configured in Alfresco?

Tags: spring, alfresco

We often inject the `nodeService` bean, `namespaceService` bean,and many more beans according to our neccesity. Where are these beans configured?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the code of Alfresco Community Edition](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition). You will find

- [`nodeService` defined in `node-services-context.xml`](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/3b6fdc1c77659d5160e8f2021cccb9db26902ee4/projects/repository/config/alfresco/node-services-context.xml#L34),
- no bean with the id `nameSpace`.
- many more beans in [`-context.xml` files](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/tree/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco).

Comment: one more question is there any specific pattern for setter method? when we are injecting the beans like suppose i am using nodeService bean and for that i just created a setter method name setNodeService() so is it neccesary? can we used diffrent setter method for nodeService?

Comment: You should read about Spring. Take a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-di-via-setter-method/

Answer (score 2):

The full code for Alfresco repo is mirrored [here](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition) . You can launch a search over there and find all occurrences of any bean you like!

Note that you may also be interested in finding both beans declarations `nodeService` and `NodeService` with a capital `N`!

By convention, beans starting with capitals in alfresco add one or more interceptors to the original bean! And this is how Alfresco does security checks, auditing and plenty of other stuff!

Comment: thanks for the replies but i could not find the configuration of NodeService bean .i just want to find out the configuration of NodeService bean in my local.

Comment: What do you mean ?